# Need lazy load approach for qtreeview & wanted to maintain only viewing items in mem

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I wanted to build a tree with lazy loading (not lazy population), The problem I have is, I have lots of data (around 10 billion to 100 billion rows) building a tree with this much data is obviously crashing tree as (memory issue). So I wanted make lazy loading (At a time I want to maintain those items which I show in view).

I have few doubts with this approach

1. I can use canFetchMore() & fetchMore() functions. when I scroll down I want to get the below items (which is possible with this functions) and I want to delete items which gone out of view.
   Loading data when scroll down can get from above functions but how to get the data when I scroll up ??
2. how can I delete items which gone out of view when I scroll ??
3. how can I maintain scroll bar size with this approach ??
4. last but one is I wanted to implement filter also on top of this.

I have seen fetchMore() example but its for list & where items are not getting deleted when gone out of view. I want to get same behavior but with a tree & want to delete items which gone out of view & want to maintain scroll bar properly.

any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `QTreeView` and custom `QAbstractItemModel` implementation. You can decide entirely how your model operates with file storage and memory. For example, you can read data from file randomly when they are requested and put them in `QCache` for optimization. As long as the model's virtual functions (`index(), parent(), rowCount(), columnCount(), and data()` are required) operate correctly, the view should be able to display data.

1. You don't need `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore`. Those functions won't help much in your case.
2. The view doesn't keep item objects, so you don't have to delete them when they go out of viewport. In fact, there should not be any item objects: creating objects for each of millions of items can be very expensive. So there are only temporary indexes (`QModelIndex`) and temporary values (`QVariant`).
3. You can maintain correct scroll bar size and position by returning correct row count value in `rowCount()`. The view will request data of currently visible cells from model.
4. See `QSortFilterProxyModel` documentation to find out how to filter models dynamically. `QSortFilterProxyModel` should be able to use your model as source and should not consume much memory in the process.

While it works in ideal case, it's possible that some flaws in `QTreeView` implementation will cause troubles. If this happens, creating your own view class may be the only way.

Comment: But when initially I need to build the tree before it populate, I have 3 crores of rows while building tree with this data only program getting crashed.